# ISPConfig configuration alongside Apache Tomcat configuration

Tags: ubuntu

I was stumbled upon a problem, I followed up the tutorial from howtoforge to set up a web server (The perfect server running Ubuntu Server 11.10) to be able to host some Java Web Applications. So I installed all the necessary applications from this tutorial, but at the end I can't access ISPConfig from the browser of another PC. The Tomcat working just fine on port 8080 accessing it on 192.168.10.88:8080, so I set up the ISPConfig to work on port 8081, but I can't access it from 192.168.10.88:8081, and I can't understand where the problem come from, here is that part http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-11.10-ispconfig-3-p6 .

So really I need your help guys, I can't get rid of this problem, this is my first server setup :)

The uotput of `netstat -antp`:

[image]

The output of `iptable --list -n -v`:

[image]

Comment: you can make a pastebin, or edit your question to add that information. Also you can obscure any identifying IPs beforehand.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

First check these are running on `192.168.10.88` by pasting the output of `netstat -antp` like so;

```
# netstat -lntp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7022                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30381/sshd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7677/perl
```

Then check that these should be accessible from other hosts on the network, by showing the firewall rules like so;

```
# iptables --list -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1055K  433M RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0              

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 833K packets, 153M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1035  237K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

   75  6096 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
 342K  166M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
   97  4836 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
 1235 59660 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  107  5328 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: I edited first post with the outputs of each command :)

Comment: so from the first post, you can see that tomcat is running, ie is listening on port 8080, but ISPConfig is not. i.e. `netstat -lntp | grep 8081` hence either its listening on some other port, or more likely it failed to start.

Comment: According to [thispost](http://www.howtoforge.com/faq/14_41_en.html) the ispconfig log file is here; `/home/admispconfig/ispconfig/ispconfig.log` but you might have to dig about in order to paste the output to your question.

Comment: So 'netstat -lntp | grep 8081' is giving me no results at all, or do I not understand what to do? sorry, I am new to server config :)

Comment: yep, so ISPConfig is not running. Did you run the installer?, what was the output? have you tried to restart ISPConfig and what was the result, and was there anything in the log file mentioned above?

Comment: yes I installed it a few times :). The log file on the '/home/administrator/ispconfig/ispconfig.log' is empty. I restarted the server and the ISPConfig as well, no results at all

Comment: not even to the console? what was the console output

Comment: /etc/rc.d/init.d/ispconfig_server restart -> /etc/rc.d/init.d/ispconfig_server: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend running tomcat on port 8081 and leave ispconfig on 8080.